# Simple register test fails

Tags: c, pointers, microcontroller, cpu-registers

I am trying to manipulate an MCU register `ADC_CON_REG`. I want to set it's  **1. bit** to **logical 1** and then immediately check if this is true by togling an LED.

```
#define ADC_CON_REG (*((volatile unsigned int *) 0x13002020))

ADC_CON_REG = ADC_CON_REG | (1<<1);

if ((ADC_CON_REG & (1<<1)) == (1<<1) ){
  LED_on();  
}
```

My LED which previously worked won't turn on in this case. Am I missing something or is my register broken?

---

**ADD:**
So in order to enable ADC and test registers I did exactly what tutorial in the LPC3141 [user manual](http://www.nxp.com/documents/user_manual/UM10362.pdf):

[image]

This is what I came up with - ADC won't work:

```
#define ADC_R0_REG      (*((volatile unsigned int *) 0x13002000))
#define ADC_R1_REG      (*((volatile unsigned int *) 0x13002004))
#define ADC_R2_REG      (*((volatile unsigned int *) 0x13002008))
#define ADC_R3_REG      (*((volatile unsigned int *) 0x1300200C))
#define ADC_CON_REG     (*((volatile unsigned int *) 0x13002020))
#define ADC_CSEL_REG        (*((volatile unsigned int *) 0x13002024))
#define ADC_INT_ENABLE_REG  (*((volatile unsigned int *) 0x13002028))
#define ADC_INT_STATUS_REG  (*((volatile unsigned int *) 0x1300202C))
#define ADC_INT_CLEAR_REG   (*((volatile unsigned int *) 0x13002030))


//prototypes
void adc_reset(void);
void adc_setup(void);
unsigned int adc_run_continuous(void);

//variables (each chanel)
unsigned int val_0;
unsigned int val_1;
unsigned int val_2;
unsigned int val_3;


void c_entry(void){

  MODE1_SET = MODE1_SET | (0x1 << 14);

  adc_reset();
  adc_setup();
  adc_run_continuous();

} 

void adc_reset(void){

  ADC_CON_REG = ADC_CON_REG & !(1<<1);  
  ADC_CON_REG = ADC_CON_REG & !(1<<3);
  ADC_CON_REG = ADC_CON_REG & !(1<<0);
  ADC_CON_REG = ADC_CON_REG & !(1<<2);
  ADC_CSEL_REG = ADC_CSEL_REG & !(0xFFFF);
  ADC_INT_ENABLE_REG = ADC_INT_ENABLE_REG & !(1<<0);
  ADC_INT_CLEAR_REG = ADC_INT_CLEAR_REG | (1<<0);

}

void adc_setup(void){

  while((ADC_INT_STATUS_REG & (1<<0)) != 0x0);
  ADC_INT_ENABLE_REG = ADC_INT_ENABLE_REG | (1<<0);
  while((ADC_INT_STATUS_REG & (1<<0)) != 0x0);
  ADC_CON_REG = ADC_CON_REG | (1<<0); 
  ADC_CSEL_REG = ADC_CSEL_REG & !(0xFFFF);
  ADC_CSEL_REG = ADC_CSEL_REG | 0xAAAA;
  ADC_CON_REG = ADC_CON_REG | (1<<1);  

}


void adc_run_continuous(void){

  ADC_CON_REG = ADC_CON_REG | (1<<2);
  ADC_CON_REG = ADC_CON_REG | (1<<3);
  ADC_CON_REG = ADC_CON_REG & !(1<<3);

  while(1){
    while((ADC_INT_STATUS_REG & (1<<0)) == 0x0);

    if((ADC_INT_STATUS_REG & (1<<0)) == 0x1){
       ADC_INT_CLEAR_REG = ADC_INT_CLEAR_REG | (1<<0);
    } 

    val_0 = ADC_R0_REG;
    val_1 = ADC_R1_REG;
    val_2 = ADC_R2_REG;
    val_3 = ADC_R3_REG;

    while((ADC_INT_STATUS_REG & (1<<0)) != 0x0);

  }


}
```

Comment: This register is a piece of hardware. Writing some bits won't necessary will actually modify them when reading. Probably it is in some state that it can't be changed in.

Comment: It is a **read / write** (R/W) register. So this shouldn't be a problem I think.

Comment: It is not a problem to write. But the problem, that reading afterwards is not what you expect. It can be written, but then changed back immediately by the hardware.

Comment: Since it's a status register, I would suggest not to write it directly but use a control register to enable/disable it.

Comment: Now I am totaly confused. Why would a manufacturer state that it can be read if it actually cant be? It is a control register -- hence the name "ADC control register".

Comment: Yeah, sorry. It is control. Got the "status" from my head, I guess.

Comment: Think that your ADC is not configured properly and cannot transition to an operational state, so setting the "operational" bit won't yield any sensible result, and it will remain non-operational.

Comment: It is conceivable that there is a delay between when you update the control register and when you can successfully read back the updated register value, in which case you may be trying too soon to read it back.  I would hope to see such a limitation documented, but it's not safe to assume that it actually would be.

Comment: if you look three pages down the user manual you showed, you'll find the "programming guide" which shows you the initialization sequence you'll probably need to follow

Comment: The problem there is that I haven't managed to study interrupts yet and they are mentioned in the "programming guide"...

Comment: Like Eugene said, most likely the peripheral is not configured to where it can enter an operational state.  If you *think* it is, the most commonly missed thing bringing up a new peripheral is the clock tree initialization.

Comment: Other registers from the same peripheral were tested the same way and they worked... But not all... They all share the same clock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a misunderstanding of what a register is. Some register is like a memory, you write logic 1 and read back, it's still logic 1. But for some register(or some bits of a register) it isn't like a memory, "write to" and "Read from" doesn't operate a true bus address behind the register.

The ADC CTRL register in some of LPCxxx MCU is an example. When you write logic 1 to the ADC enable bit, behind the register ADC starts doing the enable action, but it take times, this bit will not turn to logic 1 until the enable action finished.

So you should wait this bit change to 1 like this:

```
while ((ADC_CON_REG & (1<<1)) != (1<<1) );
LED_on();
```

Comment: Thank you for this info and sugesstion.

Answer (score 1):

There are several potential problems.

1. The register may not be mapped to an address which is accessible by the code.  The LPC314x has layer upon layer of modes which have to be set to enable various subsystems.  It is possible there is more to do than merely access the address of this one (though it might be possible).  See the [*"user" manual*](http://www.nxp.com/documents/user_manual/UM10362.pdf) for full details.  It can be *very difficult* to find all the applicable modes in the documentation.
2. The address of the register might be memory mapped somewhere else.  In user mode (as opposed to kernel mode), it may not be accessible at all.
3. There is often no reason to consider the register's write contents be related to its read contents.  While much hardware is designed to be rational in that the same bits written can be read back, that is not always the case.

Comment: **1.)** In the user manual you specified there is a "programming guide" on page 324. I tried to follow this guide, but there are unclarities. Please read ADD2 to my anwser. **2.)** I am not using OS. I am doing this in bare metal and have done no remapping so far. **3.)** I agree that this is not always the case, but for LPC this is usually indicated by marking registers with either **R** or **W**, but not **R/W** which means read & write...